# DC-DC boost converter voltage spike at power on, popping sound

Tags: power, audio

I'm using a 3.3V DC-DC boost converter (https://www.torexsemi.com/file/xcl101/XCL101.pdf) as the power source for my audio circuit. There is a popping sound (headphone output) that happens when the circuit is turned on. There is no audible noise after power up. I viewed the boost converter's output on my scope at power up, and there's an AC-coupled voltage spike of about 2.5V that quickly decays back to zero:

[image]

I'm using 10 uF capacitors at the input and output of the boost converter, as shown in the datasheet:

[image]

How can I eliminate this AC-coupled voltage transient that's creating the popping sound?

Edit: I don't have any popping noise issue when using a bench power supply. It's only a problem using the boost converter. This is my audio circuit:

[image]

I put the 1k resistor at the output in an attempt to eliminate the popping sound, as a discharge resistor. There is a large decoupling capacitance at the output because I needed a low cut off frequency. The op amps are power op amps that have the required current capability.

I tried using a different 3.3V booster circuit, and did not hear the pop sound. The booster IC is different, and the circuit includes a diode and 68 uF output cap:
[image]

Datasheet of 3.3V booster: https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/NCP1402.pdf

Comment: "I viewed the boost converter's output on my scope at power up, and there's an AC-coupled voltage spike of about 2.5V that quickly decays back to zero": well yes, the voltage was 0 before turning on and then became 3.3V after turning on, that's not DC.

Answer (score 1):

The voltage spike you're seeing is because you're switching the power on. When you go from 0 volts to 3.3v in a couple of ms, that will appear as AC when your scope is set to AC. The issue is not your power supply, the issue is your audio driver that doesn't compensate for startup pops.

Edit:

One way might be to follow [this](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/beginners/de-pop-circuit-for-audio-during-vcc-on/) suggestion like so

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fr0hdU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R2 charges C2 up slowly, gradually turning on the mosfet over a couple of milliseconds, reducing the volume of the pop. You'll need to select an op amp that can handle the amount of power that you're putting into your speaker.

Comment: When I use my bench power supply, there is no popping sound on power up. It's only an issue using the boost converter. How do you compensate for the start up pop?

Comment: In order to answer that, it'd help if you posted your audio circuit

Comment: I just edited in the audio circuit.

Comment: In that case, a small mosfet such as a BS170 would work

Comment: Is there a way to eliminate the pop rather than reduce it? I actually tried using a digital delay circuit that delayed the connection of the headphones to audio, so the circuit powers up, and then half a second later the headphones are connected to audio. There was still a small popping sound on power up, and a slightly louder popping sound at half a second. I'm not sure why. ...Would you expect this mosfet/RC configuration to have a different effect than this type of delay circuit, because it seems like you're doing the same thing?

Comment: The mosfet circuit smoothes out the transient, so instead of looking like the sharp peak on your oscilloscope, it looks more like a wide hump. This reduces the amount of high frequency noise (which your ears are better at hearing, and the speaker is better at producing), as well as reducing the overall amplitude of the noise.

Comment: How did you choose the values of R2 and C2, and what is the purpose of R3? Is there a name for this type of configuration? Why can't a normal RC filter fix the problem without using the mosfet?
Thank you!

Comment: I just tried a different 3.3V booster (breakout board from Sparkfun) and did not hear a popping sound. This is the schematic: https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/NCP1402_33V_step-up-v10.pdf   Could it be the diode from LX to VOUT that prevents the popping?

Comment: No. Most likely the power supply starts up slower. I found R2 and C2 by experimenting in a spice simulator, and R3 is for discharging the capacitor when power is removed

Comment: Don't diodes suppress transient voltages?

Comment: No? That diode either pulls up the EN pin when the power is switched on, or is a part of the boost circuitry. It doesn’t have anything to do with transients

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your power supply, Cl is only 10 uF, which allows a fast rise time of the output voltage.

To dampen that 'pulse' you can add a series resistor of 5 to 10 ohms at 3 to 5 watts, and another capacitor of 470 uF to ground so you have a heavy duty power filter.

It may not be wise to replace Cl with a high value capacitor, as it may become unstable, which is why I isolated them with a resistor.

Comment: I just tried a different 3.3V booster (breakout board from Sparkfun) and did not hear a popping sound. This is the schematic: cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/… Could it be the diode from LX to VOUT that prevents the popping?

Comment: No. It is the value of the Vcc capacitor that dampens the Vcc rise time, and helps with bass response

Comment: What's the purpose of the diode? Could it be that the different booster chip on the Sparkfun breakout board is better?

Comment: I can't use the link as I am on my cell phone.

Comment: I just added the Sparkfun breakout schematic as an edit to my question.

Comment: It is the large 68uF cap filtering out thumps.

Comment: How is the 68 uF value selected? I don't know if it would have the same effect with the 3.3V booster IC that I'm using. Also what's the purpose of the diode?

Comment: The mtg select the capacitor. The diode is a clamp. Goodnight.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you will not get away with just more capacitance here and there. You need to specifically enable th7ngs after voltage is stable. Most straightforward option is to disconnect the speaker until everything stabilize and then to connect it. You can do it with mosfet or ssr. Maybe using amplifier with "enable" input could also help. I recall that audio amplifiers usually suppress those pops by themselves.

Comment: The op amps have pop suppression listed as a feature, and they can't be causing the problem because there is no popping sound when I use my bench power supply instead of the 3.3V booster. I actually just tried using a different 3.3V booster (Sparkfun breakout board: https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/NCP1402_33V_step-up-v10.pdf) and there's no popping sound. Now I'm wondering whether the issue is with the different booster chip, or is it because the Sparkfun circuit includes a diode from LX to VOUT? The only other difference is Sparkfun's 68 uF on the output instead of 10 uF.

Comment: I would guess that the other boosters have a lower slew rate. It kind of makes sense because much lower frequency and bigger inductor.

Comment: The Sparkfun 3.3V booster does have a bigger inductor- it's a separate part. The inductor is actually built in to the small Torex 3.3V booster. I thought it was an advantage to not need a separate inductor component! Maybe not. I wonder if using a 68 uF capacitor on the Torex booster output would make a difference.

Comment: I know, i am just saying that torex inductor is small

Comment: So the question is whether the issue will be solved by using a larger 68 uF capacitor at the booster's output, or if the inductor built into the booster is too small for that capacitance to fix the problem, and I'll need to use a booster with a larger inductor, correct?

Comment: You didn't understand me. The issue MAY be caused by fast slew rate of Torex, which is natural because of it's high switching frequency, which i don't know what it is, but it is surely high for small inductor and capacitor.

Comment: The solution can be replacing the power supply, but can also be something else. Depends on your project.

Answer (score 0):

@C_Elegans answer is correct, this turn-on pop is caused by the coupling capacitors at the output charging up.

Here is another way to eliminate turn-on pop.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fI8jS3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the power is turned on, the voltage across C1 is 0 (it is discharged by R3 when the power is off), so current is flowing through D1 and the opamp will output 0. As C1 charges through R5 and R6, the opamp will assume it's steady-state output of +V/2. Choose C1R5 to prevent a 'pop' from being heard (i.e. much more than 8ms).