# How to prevent single-rail amplifier power-on pop sound?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, audio, single-supply-op-amp

I am building a 9 V battery-powered microphone pre-amplifier and I'm encountering a design problem which I don't know how to solve.

I have an op-amp that serves as main amplifier which is powered by a battery using a ground and 9 V rail. In the context of this question I think this circuit is sufficient to explain my situation (values are not accurate and circuit is not complete):

[image]

My main problem is that whenever I close SW1 to turn on the device, I get a loud pop sound at the output because C4 is not yet charged (at least that's what my simulation is telling me).

I'd prefer to use the smallest circuit possible and a circuit with very low quiescent currents. There are two ways I've considered:

- Somehow make the main amplifier supply rise very slowly when SW1 is closed
- Somehow short R5 when the device is turned on. I've considered using an n-channel MOSFET, but I'm not sure if I can reliably make sure it's always shorting R5 fast enough.

Would one of these be the way to solve this and if so, what would a circuit look like?

I've also looked at this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/355225/dc-dc-boost-converter-voltage-spike-at-power-on-popping-sound). Since I'm not hooking up a speaker: Would disconnecting my output ground using a MOSFET work like in answer 1? Unfortunately I don't understand answer 2 at all.

Comment: I've seen many commercial (HiFi) appliances do this with a simple relay + timer.

Comment: How is the amplifier volume controlled? Does it have a mute input or a way you can start it without the volume at max? Not sure that's a cure, necessarily. But if available, it should be tried. A common way is a delayed relay. But that may be more than you want to bite off.

Comment: I've considered a relay, though, do relays typically operate at less than 1ma?

Comment: You could try a **capacitor-multiplier PNP** to ramp up the supply slowly, but stages downstream will still  have a click when you reach +8.8V and level out.

Comment: @thelpatix, look into latching relays. Only take a pulse to engage and disengage them. But then you'll need a delay, and way to "reset it" on power-off.

Comment: You can put a time delay MOSFET switch after C4 that only turn on after the pop has occurred. Simple N-channel MOSFET series switch with RC that turns on the gate. I am assuming that 9V from the battery is much higher than the highest part of your signal of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that C3 is causing the POP. It is eliminated by slowing down the biasing like this:
[image: POP]

Comment: At least in simulation this indeed seems to remove the giant output step I get. I guess I'll have to wire up an actual example and test it. As for the component values: They we're not accurate in the schematic I provided. Maybe a poor attempt by me to break down the circuit to the minimum for the question.